# Please help me to solve this

Tags: sql, oracle

I have crated two table one is cutomer and other one is ord

```
select * from customers;
```

Customer table

```
1   101 jun 23  yyyy    15000
2   102 jas 24  zzzz    10000
3   103 fat 20  kkkk    20000
4   104 jini    40  llll    30000
5   105 michael 30  dddd    25000
6   106 das 25  hhhh    10000
7   107 vijay   26  mmmm    12000
8   108 thanku  31  jjjj    26000
9   109 vishnu  34  gggg    24000
10  110 vas 28  ffff    18000

select * from ord;
```

This is order table

```
1       12/11/2013 1:00:00 AM   102 2500
2   202 12/11/2013 4:14:17 AM   102 3000
3   203 12/9/2013 9:18:16 PM    103 2000
4   204 12/8/2013 12:00:00 PM   102 1000
5   205 12/24/2013  107 2000
```

This is tha union command that I have used

```
select c.name,c.salary,o.amount 
from CUSTOMERS c
inner join ord o
on c.id=o.customer_id;
```

then the resulting table is

```
1   jas 10000   1000
2   jas 10000   3000
3   jas 10000   2500
4   fat 20000   2000
5   vijay   12000   2000
```

I want resulting table like this

```
1      jas      10000   6500
2      fat      20000   2000
3      vijay    12000   2000
```

plz help me for solving this.

Comment: Please use a more speaking title describing your questions. This lets others find and evaluate your questions more easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`group by c.name, c.salary` with `sum(salary)` is what you want:

```
select c.name, c.salary, sum(o.amount )
from CUSTOMERS c
inner join ord o on c.id=o.customer_id
group by c.name, c.salary;
```

Comment: Thanks Mahamoud Gamal it working.... :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this if it will work.

```
    select c.name,c.salary,sum(o.amount)
    from CUSTOMERS c
    inner join ord o
    on c.id=o.customer_id
    group by 1,2;
```

Thanks.

Comment: change the 1,2 to column names. select c.name,c.salary,sum(o.amount)
    from CUSTOMERS c
    inner join ord o
    on c.id=o.customer_id
    group by c.name,c.salary;

Comment: At first try is used 1,2 with group funtion thats why I cant get the answaer

Comment: I used the wrong syntax, 1,2 works in mysql but not in oracle. Glad to help. :)

Comment: ah k and I need more helps from you.. :-)

Comment: Ok. i'll be glad. can you try to accept the answer? Thanks.

Comment: I dont know how to accept the answer

Comment: just click the check icon on the side. thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select c.name,c.salary,SUM(o.amount )
from CUSTOMERS c
inner join ord o
on c.id=o.customer_id
GROUP BY c.name,c.salary
```

I think this will work

Answer (score 0):

Use `Left Join` or `RIGHT JOIN`

```
select c.name,c.salary,o.amount 
from CUSTOMERS c
left join ord o
on c.id=o.customer_id;
```